# How set VLC as my app default Video player Flutter

Tags: flutter, vlc

I writing an App that I want to use VLC Media Player as an external app in my App as a default video player.
I test the VLC package for flutter but it doesn't support many features like subtitle, multi sounds track movie and etc. 
I saw in many apps which they allow the user to choose an external player as the default player. How can I set this in Flutter?

Comment: This plugin allows add VLC to flutter app but I want to ad dit by myself to customize it as I need https://pub.dev/packages/mx_player_plugin

Comment: this plugin doesn't work for VLC on iOS